# Order of Operations in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, operator-precedence

Has the order of operations changed in Google sheets?

If I enter in a cell

```
=1-1-1^2
```

I obtain -1

But if I enter

```
=-1^2
```

I obtain 1

If remember correctly, when I started using Google Sheets a few years ago, both expressions gave the same result -1. I was pleased that Google sheets had not adopted the irritating and deprecated Excel feature of giving the minus sign priority in the order of operations if it appeared by itself. But now I see that Google Sheets adopted the same rule as Excel. If I'm right, and Google somewhere down the road has decided to convert to the deprecated Excel habit, when was the order of operations altered?

Answer (score 1):

logic of:

> =1-1-1^2

is:

```
=1-1-(1^2)
```

if you expect the result to be 1 then you should write it as:

```
=1-1+(-1^2)
```

raising on the power is the top priority (as it should) over the minus sign (unless you use parenthesis) which are able to overwrite this priority and treat the minus as part of 1

pretty much the same as the windows calculator:

[image]

or google:

[image]

---

> Has the order of operations changed in Google sheets?

no, it hasn't

> when was the order of operations altered?

it wasn't. if you by any chance experienced different behavior then it was only fixed to reflect the current propper state

Comment: Sorry, but that was not my question. There are two questions, and both end with a question mark; I thought that was clear.